# Virtualbox VPN settings

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I can connect to a VPN using NetworkManager, but I can't do it from Windows XP running as a guest OS. Unfortunately, the VPN is only to access local servers in my organization, and it isn't "connected" to Internet. So I can't surf the web while doing my work in guest OS. Disconnecting each time I want to surf is unacceptable, because since I work with databases, I need stable connection to the servers where they are located.

How do I configure VirtualBox so I can connect to VPN from inside the Guest OS? Currently I have "NAT" setting, how should I change it? Should I create a separate virtual interface in my Lubuntu so that I can somehow bridge the guest OS to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was quite easy. All you have to do is to switch network mode of virtual machine to

```
Attached to => Bridge
```

and select the network interface that provides internet connection using which you want to connect to VPN, e.g. `wlan0`